# How to test whether a service is running from the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to be able to query whether or not a service is running from a windows batch file. I know I can use:

> sc query "ServiceName"

but, this dumps out some text. What I really want is for it to set the `errorlevel` environment variable so that I can take action on that.

Do you know a simple way I can do this?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answers so far. I'm worried the solutions that parse the text may not work on non English operating systems. Does anybody know a way around this, or am I going to have to bite the bullet and write a console program to get this right.

Comment: I just tested on a China locale Chinese Language Windows 7 laptop, the "sc query ..." command output are still English.

Comment: To get service state that will be easy to parse by script no matter what OS language is used I have used `WMIC Service WHERE "Name = 'SericeName'" GET Started /format:list`. It produces `State=Running` - easy to parse by regexp and always in English.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
sc query "ServiceName" | find "RUNNING"
```

Comment: @ShaiAlon, it was powershell that it did not work. It worked on the usual command prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: It does not work on powershell because sc is an alias to Set-Content.

Comment: `sc.exe query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING` will work within Powershell.

Comment: is there a way to use regex search while looking for a particular service name? Sometimes I maynot remember exactly what the name is but I would know parts of the name..

Comment: If the task is to start a service in case it is not running, then testing for the `STOPPED` status is much safer, for the service may also be in one of the transitory states `STARTING` and `STOPPING`, when it is best left alone.

Answer (score 19):

Let's go back to the old school of batch programing on windows

```
net start | find "Service Name"
```

This will work everywhere...

Comment: _errorlevel_ is 1 both when the service exists or not. So I can't use "find". (Win 7 Pro 64 bit)

Comment: @RealHowTo, I am running "MobaSSH", and if I open the "Services" app from Control panel, I can check that "MobaSSH" is working. Further, the command you mentioned, `net start | find "MobaSSH"` also prints out "MobaSSH", indiciating that this command works. However, if I use the `sc query "MobaSSH" | find "RUNNING"` command, it shows an error saying "EnumQueryServicesStatus: Open Service Failed 1060". Any idea why these 2 commands are showing different results?

Comment: When I use default Windows services such as "Fax", both commands give similar results. Also `sc query` does work.. but its not working for "MobaSSH". is there something special about a service initiated by an external program?

Comment: Isn't net start the command to start a service? The question is to check if the service is running, not start it

Comment: @trees_are_great using `net start` alone will list all "started" services.

Comment: Will work on both cmd and ps but there one should keep the [differences between `net` and `sc`](https://superuser.com/a/315172/447380) in mind.

Answer (score 8):

if you don't mind to combine the net command with grep you can use the following script.

```
@echo off
net start | grep -x "Service"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto trouble
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto stopped
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto started
echo unknown status
goto end
:trouble
echo trouble
goto end
:started
echo started
goto end
:stopped
echo stopped
goto end
:end
```

Comment: I don't seem to have grep on my system. Did you download it from somewhere, if so, where?

Comment: I've used something like this, but with a 'find' instead of a 'grep' because I don't want to have to rely on installing anything else.

Comment: @ScottLangham Does find have regex searching capability?

Comment: @alpha_989 No. If you're on windows, start command prompt and type "find /?" to see the help for it.

Comment: Grep is not a default windows tool

Answer (score 7):

You could use wmic with the [/locale](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787035.aspx) option

```
call wmic /locale:ms_409 service where (name="wsearch") get state /value | findstr State=Running
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    echo Running
) else (
    echo Not running
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Thinking a little bit outside the box here I'm going to propose that powershell may be an answer on up-to-date XP/2003 machines and certainly on Vista/2008 and newer (instead of .bat/.cmd).  Anyone who has some Perl in their background should feel at-home pretty quickly.

```
$serviceName = "ServiceName";
$serviceStatus = (get-service "$serviceName").Status;

if ($serviceStatus -eq "Running") {
    echo "Service is Running";
}
else {
    #Could be Stopped, Stopping, Paused, or even Starting...
    echo "Service is $serviceStatus";
}
```

Another way, if you have significant investment in batch is to run the PS script as a one-liner, returning an exit code.

```
@ECHO off
SET PS=powershell -nologo -command
%PS% "& {if((get-service SvcName).Status -eq 'Running'){exit 1}}"

ECHO.%ERRORLEVEL%
```

Running as a one-liner also gets around the default PS code signing policy at the expense of messiness.  To put the PS commands in a .ps1 file and run like `powershell myCode.ps1` you may find signing your powershell scripts is neccessary to run them in an automated way (depends on your environment). See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx for details

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
REM testing at cmd : sc query "MSSQLSERVER" | findstr RUNNING
REM "MSSQLSERVER" is the name of Service for sample
sc query "MSSQLSERVER" %1 | findstr RUNNING
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto trouble
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto stopped
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto started
echo unknown status
goto end
:trouble
echo Oh noooo.. trouble mas bro
goto end
:started
echo "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" is started
goto end
:stopped
echo "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" is stopped
echo Starting service
net start "MSSQLSERVER"
goto end
:erro
echo Error please check your command.. mas bro 
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sc query state= all
```

for a list of services and whether they are running or not.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest 
`WMIC Service WHERE "Name = 'SericeName'" GET Started`

or `WMIC Service WHERE "Name = 'ServiceName'" GET ProcessId` (ProcessId will be zero if service isn't started)

You can set the error level based on whether the former returns "TRUE" or the latter returns nonzero

Comment: This is actually the only way to get service state that will always return value in English no matter what is the OS language.

Answer (score 3):

```
sc query "servicename" | findstr STATE
```

for example:

```
sc query "wuauserv" | findstr STATE
```

To report what the Windows update service is doing, running/paused etc.
This is also for Windows 10. Thank me later.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this:

```
  sc query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING
```

seems to do roughly the right thing. But, I'm worried that's not generalized enough to work on non-english operating systems.

Comment: If you really need to do i18n, you should write an app which queries and sets the errorlevel.

Comment: how to access the answer of the command `sc query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING` so with conditional statements i can do some processing

Answer (score 2):

```
SERVICO.BAT
@echo off
echo Servico: %1
if "%1"=="" goto erro
sc query %1 | findstr RUNNING
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto trouble
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto stopped
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto started
echo unknown status
goto end
:trouble
echo trouble
goto end
:started
echo started
goto end
:stopped
echo stopped
goto end
:erro
echo sintaxe: servico NOMESERVICO
goto end

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the list if you are using Powershell.

```
sc.exe query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING
```

The command below does not work because `sc` is an alias to Set-Content within Powershell.

```
sc query "ServiceName" | findstr RUNNING
```

`find` also does not work on Powershell for some reason unknown to me.

```
sc.exe query "ServiceName" | find RUNNING
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed no one mentioned the use of regular expressions when using `find`/`findstr`-based Answers. That can be problematic for similarly named services.

Lets say you have two services, `CDPUserSvc` and `CDPUserSvc_54530`

If you use most of the `find`/`findstr`-based Answers here so far, you'll get false-positives for `CDPUserSvc` queries when only `CDPUserSvc_54530` is running.

The `/r` and `/c` switches for `findstr` can help us handle that use-case, as well as the special character that indicates the end of the line, `$`

This query will only verify the running of the `CDPUserSvc` service and ignore `CDPUserSvc_54530`

`sc query|findstr /r /c:"CDPUserSvc$"`

Answer (score 1):

A suggested approach can be found in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987266/): *target very specific things which are locale-independent*. In this case, for obtaining service status from `sc.exe`, the integer which identifies the state was found to be independent of active language and, therefore, robust.

Short example (additional details in the linked answer):

```bat
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3" %%i in ('""%windir%\system32\sc.exe" query "W32Time" 2^>nul"') do (
  if "%%i"=="4" (
    echo 'W32Time' service is running
    goto :SkipRemainingIterations
  )
)
:SkipRemainingIterations
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) Bash with:

```
sc query "SomeService" |grep -qo RUNNING && echo "SomeService is running." || echo "SomeService is not running!"
```

(Make sure you have `sc.exe` in your PATH.)

Answer (score -1):

I have created one based from above but will show if the service is installed first then get whether it is running or not.

```
sc query "YourService" | find /i "failed" 2>&1>nul && echo.'YourService Not Installed' || (sc query "YourService"| find /i "running" 2>&1>nul && echo.Yes || echo.No)
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit hard to read and understand. Please clarify what it does, and ideally convert the code into multiple lines so it's easier to grasp.