# Batch file to check if a system service is running

Tags: windows, service, batch-file

I would like to know how to check if a service is running using a batch file

e.g.

if xxxx service is running
go to start stage2.bat
else go to echo Service not running

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I have found the solution, for anyone else having this problem:

Comment: echo off
sc query PeerDistSvc
if %errorlevel% == 1060 echo Could not start service.
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service started successfully.
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

EDIT:
From the post, with an added else statement:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    call stage2.bat
) else (
    echo Program is not running
)
```

For a service:

```
sc query "ServiceName" | find "RUNNING"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    call stage2.bat
) else (
    echo Program is not running
)
```

Comment: Hi it is, but it doesn't include any else statements :(

Comment: Hi, thank you, although how would you do this with a service though, oposed to a process

Comment: Ah, james, you're right, i was thinking that services had corresponding processes, but this isn't always true.  In this case, you'll need to use sc query per PA's post.  look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353161/how-to-test-whether-a-service-is-running-from-the-command-line

Comment: Cheers, pretty much what I figured out :)

Answer (score 4):

read this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192 and see `SC /?`

then try

`SC QUERY`

**EDIT:**
to automate the check, pipe the result to FIND and look for RUNNING

```
 SC QUERY %1 | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" >nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo NOT RUNNING ) ELSE (echo RUNNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

color 1F


@sc query >%COMPUTERNAME%_START.TXT

ECHO REPORT MISSING INSTALL SERVICES >%COMPUTERNAME%_MISSING.TXT


find /I "AcPrfMgrSvc" %COMPUTERNAME%_START.TXT >nul

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 NET START "AcPrfMgrSvc"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO AcPrfMgrSvc >>%COMPUTERNAME%_MISSING.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, because under Windows7 just IF `ERRORLEVEL 1` does not work and errorlevel is 0 in case `findstr` successful or not.

In my case, I'm looking for something started by *java.exe*, lets say *HELLO.jar* [parameter of java.exe]

```
    wmic PROCESS LIST FULL | findstr /I java.exe | findstr /I HELLO.jar

    if ErrorLevel 1 (
        Echo OK
        msg "%username%" HELLO.jar not started
            Pause   
    ) else (
        Echo ERR
        msg "%username%" HELLO.jar already running
            Pause
        exit
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might need admin privileges and non of the examples deals with that. If you don't make us of nircmd already you could start now

This is how I do it anyways. When my bluetooth stops working

```
set _ServiceName=CSRBtAudioService
 call :SrvStat %_ServiceName%
goto :SomeWhere

:SrvStat
sc query "%1" | find "RUNNING"
    if %Errorlevel% EQU 0 ( echo: restarting %1 & nircmd elevatecmd service restart %1
    ) else ( echo: starting %1 & nircmd elevatecmd service start %1 )
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking to do this on a remote system using SC. Note: Placed in the extra 'if /I "%%H"' statement for example purposes of further use.

```
SC \\host query
```

Example:

```
:: This example prints the status of a remote service 
SC \\%REMOTE_SYSTEM% query %SERVICE% | FIND "STATE" >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo RESULT: %SERVICE% is [UNKNOWN]  
 ) ELSE (
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('SC \\%REMOTE_SYSTEM% query "%SERVICE%" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
        if /I "%%H"=="STOPPED" (
            echo RESULT: %SERVICE% is %%H
        ) else (
            echo RESULT: %SERVICE% is %%H
        )
    )
)
```