# Check Jenkins Status Get Email When Service Goes Down

Tags: jenkins

I would like to know if there is a way to periodically check the status of the jenkins service and get an email when the service goes down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On linux:**
Can use `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep jenkins | wc -l` to find if your jenkins is running or not , if not try to invoke email script or restart and put it in crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
if (($(ps - ef | grep - v grep | grep $service | wc - l) > 0))
then
    echo "$service is running!!!"
else
    echo "Do your stuff!!"
fi
```

Source / example : [Link](http://www.akamaras.com/linux/linux-script-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-and-start-it-if-its-stopped/)

On localhost, you can check for the HTTP code URL assuming jenkins is running on 8080

```
#!/bin/bash
response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8080)
if [ $response  == 200 ]
then
    echo "Site is up"
else
    echo "Site is down"
    echo "Do your stuff!!"
fi
```

**On windows:** 
you can do simillar with form a batch script using:
`sc query service | findstr /i running | if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (sc stop service) else (sc start service)` 
More links to read on this

- [Stop and Start a service via batch or cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file)
- [Batch file to check if a system service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940539/batch-file-to-check-if-a-system-service-is-running)
- http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/207306-start-and-stop-services-in-a-single-batch-file/

**Other Options:**

- If you are using any monitoring service like nagios you can monitor
  jenkins service from it too.

---

[Sending mail from Python using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp)